# Android spinner in layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner

I am trying to populate a spinner but I seem to be missing something in my layout file

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> cuisines = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_view,
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cuisines));
```

I can't find R.layout.spinner_view and can only assume that I have to make it myself in my layout file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include spinner in xml file as:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and in activity:

```
Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.cuisines);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item --I can't find this one

Comment: android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item refers to default layout provided by Android for Spinner.select android layout instead of your package.

Answer (score 2):

Use `import com.companyname.product.R;`

**instead of**

`import android.R;`

Comment: So now , what do you mean by "I can't find R.layout.spinner_view", why , whats happening?

Comment: My problem was that I wasn't using android.R

Comment: @Samir make sure its **import android.R;**, not **import com.android.R**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load with default spinner view, then use,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> cuisines = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cuisines));
```

Comment: I couldnt get your comment, will you please explain?

Comment: my problem was that I was using R.layout instead of android.R.layout